# Looking for postal areas for Germany

Tags: shapefile, data, postal-code, free-software, germany

Does anyone of you know how and where I can download postal area districts of Germany in shapefiles (download free of charge if possible).

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

A more recent shapefile can be found here:

Postleitzahlen Deutschland (http://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/downloads)

Licensing same as [OpenStreetMap Copyright and License](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright/en), where the data comes from.

Answer (score 4):

You find a dowload here : http://arnulf.us/PLZ
However, the data is from 1999 and I'm not sure if it still is up-to-date.

Comment: Arnulf did a nice job back then and as far as I can tell it's the only freely available dataset. But there are many changes , although minor, changes to the postal area geometries every year. But on a small scale you should be fine.

Comment: The url is not responding. Any other sources?

Comment: I search for all but can anybody tell me which one is latest and matching with validate postal codes of Germany? because number of PLZ polygons what available in all shapfiles are around 8200. Is it matching with latest postal code (valid postal codes). If it is matching no doubts i will say big thanks to blogger.

Answer (score 1):

Arnulf Christl's personal website [arnulf.us](http://arnulf.us/PLZ), which contains the description of his public domain dataset of German postal codes, is unavailable at the moment. You can find an [archived version at the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130603091259/http://arnulf.us/PLZ).

The [dataset itself can be downloaded](http://www.metaspatial.net/download/plz.tar.gz) from the website of Arnulf's company [Metaspatial](http://www.metaspatial.net)  (alternatively, there's a [snapshot at archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130603091259/http://www.metaspatial.net/download/plz.tar.gz)).

A different dataset is a [GeoJSON file of postal codes extracted from OpenStreetMap](http://www.folge3.de/wp/2013/05/deutsche-postleitzahlen-gebiete-zum-download/) by the German company [Folge 3](http://www.folge3.de). It's a bit patchy, and not quality controlled (it includes some Spanish postal code areas, for example).

Answer (score 1):

the zip-code from Arnulf 1999 is too old,
i was used this file but it was wrong - for 5digits - i check with this svg - map http://www.maps4office.com/interaction-svg-maps/ - and level 8 (zip-code) was right.

my german is not good but i change to DE:
http://www.maps4office.de/shop-detail/deutschland-citymarker/citymarker-de-postleitzahlen-fuenfstellig/  and the map is from 2014 ... but it's not free